# .bat file how to repeat process for each row in list.txt (creating shortcuts by list)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, vbscript, shortcut

My code now creates a shortcut to first row in "list.txt", with correct name (as last folder in target of shortcut called), but I need to do the same process with whole "list.txt", for each row, 
as if I added 'skip=1', then 'skip=2'..... to '**for /f**' for each row:

> for /f "**skip=1** usebackq delims=" %%G IN (List.txt) DO if not
>   defined line set "line=%%G"

I can't repeat this process in one bat file to each row. How to do that?

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (List.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"
set LNKNAME=%line:~0%
for %%f in ("%LNKNAME%") do set LNKNAME_A=%%~nxf
SET SAVETO=%userprofile%\desktop

    call :createLink "%LNKNAME_A%" "%line%"

pause

rem createLink <linkname> <target>
:createLink
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%SAVETO%\%~1.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%~2" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
EXIT /B 0
rem goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just expand your loop:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET "SAVETO=%userprofile%\desktop"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("List.txt") DO (
  set "line=%%G"
  set "LNKNAME=!line:~0!"
  for %%f in ("!LNKNAME!") do set "LNKNAME_A=%%~nxf"
  call :createLink "!LNKNAME_A!" "!line!"
)
pause
goto :eof
:createLink
...
```

Note: this uses [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

**Edit** 
moved `set saveto=...` out of the loop (no benefit to set it to the same value for each line)

Considering `set "LNKNAME=!line:~0!"` does nothing useful, we can remove it and use `%%G` directly. Also the `for %%f` does just get `%%~nxf` (you haven't provided an example of your text file, so I have to guess: shouldn't it be just `%%~nf`?), which is the same as `%%nxG`(`%%~nG`?), we can also remove it and use `%%G` and `%%nG` directly. This shortens the code to:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions  
SET "SAVETO=%userprofile%\desktop"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("List.txt") DO (
  call :createLink "%%~nG" "%%G"
)
...
```

(Note: no delayed expansion needed any more)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that still creates only one shortcut for the first row of List.txt, should I also change something in **:createLink** part?

Comment: Again, thank you very much!  I've just changed: `if not defined line set "line=%%G"` to `set "line=%%G"` and now it works great!

Comment: few bits shorter: `SET "SAVETO=%userprofile%\desktop"` `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (List.txt) DO if exist "%%~fG" call :createLink "%%~nxG" "%%~G"` `pause &goto :eof`

Comment: Yeah, cool! Much shorter and still doing the same, thank you!